# keyval first pair not shown

Tags: key-value

How to change the following so the name1 and caption1 is also used - not only the second pair of keys:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter 

\define@key{grid}{name1}{\def\grid@name1{#1}}
\define@key{grid}{caption1}{\def\grid@caption1{#1}}

\define@key{grid}{name2}{\def\grid@name2{#1}}
\define@key{grid}{caption2}{\def\grid@caption2{#1}}

\newcommand{\grid}[2][]{%

\begingroup%

      \setkeys{grid}{#1}  

      \grid@name1 \\  
      \grid@caption1 \\
      \grid@name2 \\  
      \grid@caption2
      
\endgroup%
 
} 
 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\grid[name1= \detokenize{name_of_file1},
    caption1=My sub caption text 1,
    name2= \detokenize{name_of_file2},
    caption2=My sub caption text 2]

\end{document}
```

Which return only:

```
name_of_file2 
My sub caption text 2
```

Comment: For one, the syntax highlighter clearly indicate something is wrong with your code i.e. you can't use number as part of command definition

Comment: and don't ignore error messages.

Comment: Thanks, using letters only did fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The following is in principle the same solution you already got from [the comments (don't use digits in macro names)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641454/keyval-first-pair-not-shown/641460#comment1598841_641454).

But this fixes a few more mistakes:

- your `\grid` macro only takes one optional argument, no mandatory one. Use `\newcommand\grid[1][]` instead of `[2][]`.
- if you use multiple consecutive blank lines this is turned into a `\par` token by TeX, this is also true for macro definitions. This is most likely not wanted (else, use an explicit `\par` to make this clear!). So I removed them.
- you don't need to put `%` after `\endgroup` (there is no space, because `\endgroup` is a control word), but you're missing a `%` after the closing brace of `\setkeys`
- `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` isn't necessary with a modern LaTeX-installation (but this is no real error)

Everything combined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter 

\define@key{grid}{name1}{\def\grid@nameA{#1}}
\define@key{grid}{caption1}{\def\grid@captionA{#1}}

\define@key{grid}{name2}{\def\grid@nameB{#1}}
\define@key{grid}{caption2}{\def\grid@captionB{#1}}

\newcommand{\grid}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
    \setkeys{grid}{#1}%
    \grid@nameA \\  
    \grid@captionA \\
    \grid@nameB \\  
    \grid@captionB
  \endgroup
} 
 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\grid[name1= \detokenize{name_of_file1},
    caption1=My sub caption text 1,
    name2= \detokenize{name_of_file2},
    caption2=My sub caption text 2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting and explaining the details.

Answer (score 0):

Using letters only, following the comment solved the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter 

\define@key{grid}{nameA}{\def\grid@nameA{#1}}
\define@key{grid}{captionA}{\def\grid@captionA{#1}}

\define@key{grid}{nameB}{\def\grid@nameB{#1}}
\define@key{grid}{captionB}{\def\grid@captionB{#1}}

\newcommand{\grid}[2][]{%

      \setkeys{grid}{#1}  

      \grid@nameA \\ 
      \grid@captionA \\
      \grid@nameB \\  
      \grid@captionB
} 
 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\grid[%  
%
nameA= \detokenize{name_of_file1.pdf}, captionA=My sub caption text 1,
nameB= \detokenize{name_of_file2.pdf}, captionB=My sub caption text 2
%
]

\end{document}

name_of_file1.pdf 
My sub caption text 1
name_of_file2.pdf
My sub caption text 2
```